# can not include lib curl in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, libcurl

Hy i  prepared a project on mac now i continued developing on windows.

My project has this strcture:

- Project

  - include

    - HttpClient.h
  - src

    - HttpClient.cpp
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - main.cpp
  - curl-8.5.0

    - ....

My base CMakeLists.txt Looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(ReadPr)

# Add the src folder to the list of directories containing source files
add_subdirectory(src)

# Add the include folder to the list of directories containing header files
include_directories(include)

# Find the curl package
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

# Add the executable and link it with the source files, curl library
add_executable(readPr main.cpp)

# Link the executable with the target in the src directory
target_link_libraries(readPr ReadPrSrc)

# Link the executable with the curl library
target_link_libraries(readPr ${CURL_LIBRARIES})

# Include the curl and jsoncpp headers
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

but in my header i can not find the #include <curl/curl.h>. I am confused why the same configuration works on mac but on windows not.

I also tried to make this change but it did not worked:

```
# Set the path to the libcurl root directory
set(CURL_ROOT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/curl-8.5.0")

# Find the curl package
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
```

can someone give me a suggestion.

Comment: are you sure `CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS` is set? It's more reliable to link to `CURL::libcurl` rather than using the variables as you'll get an error if there are any typos

Comment: Does your windows machine  have a global installation of curl? If not, do that first. Even better, use vcpkg or conan to drive the automatic installation of curl from your CMake script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Botje
Thanks for the tip I feel so silly now I change my cmake to download the lib now directly from the repo to avoid this problem for this I changed the import to this:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(curl
    URL https://curl.se/download/curl-8.5.0.tar.gz
    DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP true
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(curl)
```